# Request for Google Password for Calendar Updates

Tags: passwords, google

A website that I trust (Delta Airlines) offers a link to add flight information to Google Calendar; that link opens a window asking for my Google login and password. Based on the advice in a similar question ([Can apps be trusted when requesting your credentials?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6865/can-apps-be-trusted-when-requesting-your-credentials)) as well as my own skepticism, there's no way I'm providing my main Google password to Delta, even if it would work (which it probably wouldn't because I have 2-factor authentication set up with Google).

But Google has an "App Password" service set up for apps that can't handle 2-factor authentication. My question is: Would it be reasonably prudent to set up a Google app password for the Delta website, provide that password on the Delta interface, and then revoke the password after the calendar update is made?

(I assume Delta wants to create the calendar entry using a password, rather than a direct URL for which no password is required, so that they can update that entry with flight changes. And I realize that by revoking the password I would lose this functionality. I would prefer to take this risk of missing automated flight updates, forcing me to monitor flight changes directly, than to take the risk of leaving the Delta password active.)

Comment: It seems to me you would be going through more trouble than simply adding it yourself to your calendar.

Comment: Well, I thought the community would consider it off-topic for me to delve into my personal preferences, as these don't contribute to a question with broad applicability -- so I limited my initial post to (1) the question and (2) enough background information to show that I've made a good-faith effort to research it on my own. But if this is important to anyone who might help: In the past I've made typographical errors when adding calendar entries, and I don't want to make such an error in something as important as an airline reservation.

Comment: Also, I disagree with the premise that the app password is a lot of trouble. It's a two- or three-click process on the Google account management screen -- which is an interface I'm very familiar and comfortable with. (It certainly is a lot less trouble than actually purchasing the airline ticket.)

Comment: You know, gmail automatically generates calendar events off things like airplane reservations. I wouldn't give account access like that for a one-time deal. Does Delta present you with the Google login screen, or is it their own thing?

Comment: It's their own thing. And I realize now that the version they put on their ticket confirmation screen (which is what I was asking about) is different from what they put on the trip review screen. The latter uses Google OAuth, which I feel much better about.